# Vi works, but not Vim

Tags: vim, zsh, vi

I am running a zsh shell on MacOS High Sierra. Until recently, I have used `vim` for all my programming needs.

Yesterday, seemingly without cause, vim stopped working on my computer. When I try to open/create a file like so, `vim any_file.txt`, the terminal cursor blinks indefinitely and does nothing. I've restarted the computer and reinstalled `vim` with `brew`, to no avail.

What's most bizarre is that `vi` has no problem, and recognizes all the settings I've specified in my `~/.vimrc`. I don't mind using `vi` for the time being, but it would give me peace of mind to know why `vim` is acting up and how I might fix that.

Comment: On Mac OS X and many other UNIX variants and derivatives, `vi` is actually Vim or another `vi` clone so, whether you type that extra `m` or not, you are still using Vim. Now, for the reason why the `vim` command is not accessible anymore… I have no idea.

Comment: What happens if you run vim without your vimrc? `vim -u NONE`

Comment: I recommend to migrate to https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the output of `whence -av vi vim`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this can help:

First, deinstall:

```
$ brew uninstall vim
```

Cleanup:

```
$ brew cleanup -s
```

Install:

```
$ brew install vim --with-override-system-vi
```